# how to auto detect page break on the client with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, page-break

Is there any way to detect where the page break would be and change my data accordingly, not with the media print but on the client?

ie, i have a table with many rows, if i add another row the page break with change.

see the plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/mDOGtpDSfmwhCjK15PMO?p=preview

the page will break on row 29, if i add a row on table1 OR on table2 the page break should still be on row 29.

click the print to see the result.

currently i have a ng-repeat with the following code for adding a line.

```
$scope.add = function(index, table){
    var array = angular.copy($scope[table]);
    var nextId = array.length + 1 ;
    $scope[table].splice(index, 0,{id:nextId, name:'new line'})
  }
```

What i am trying to accomplish is to show on the client an accurate representation of what the print out would be.

therefore if i can detect when the page break WILL be (depending on the data), i can arrange the css of the client to represent the print out.

i hope that makes sense
any ideas on how to go about it?

CLARIFICATION:  I am not asking on how to use page-break-inside and @media print because that reflects only the printout.

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean by "page break"?  A new page when you "print"?

Comment: yes.  that is correct